# Get time difference using current time

Tags: c

I made a Math game for my Kid (8 years old) and at some point i decided to show him how much time did he needed to answer to that question, so i decided to use the function time here.

I wrote the following program:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct setClock{
    int hour;
    int minutes;
    int seconds;
};

struct setClock currTime(void);
void timeCheck(struct setClock myClock[2]);

int main(void){
    struct setClock myClock[2];

    myClock[0] = currTime();
    printf("Start Time: %d:%d:%d\n\n", myClock[0].hour, myClock[0].minutes, myClock[0].seconds );

    sleep(5);

    myClock[1] = currTime();
    printf("End Time:   %d:%d:%d\n", myClock[1].hour, myClock[1].minutes, myClock[1].seconds );

    timeCheck(myClock);

    return 0;

}

struct setClock currTime(void){
    struct setClock ret;
    struct tm *tm;
    time_t myTime;

    myTime=time(NULL);
    tm=localtime(&myTime);

    ret.hour = tm->tm_hour;
    ret.minutes = tm->tm_min;
    ret.seconds = tm->tm_sec;

    return ret;
}

void timeCheck(struct setClock myClock[2]){
    int hour;
    int minute;

    time_t end, start;
    double diff;

    start = (time_t)((myClock[0].hour * 60 + myClock[1].hour) * 60) ;
    end   = (time_t)((myClock[0].minutes * 60 + myClock[1].minutes) * 60) ;

    if( end < start ){
        end += 24 * 60 * 60 ;
    }

    diff = difftime(end, start);

    hour = (int) diff / 3600;
    minute = (int) diff % 3600 / 60;
    printf("\n\n");
    printf("The elapsed time is  %d Hours - %d Minutes\n", hour, minute);
}
```

When i run it, i get different outputs like:

```
Start Time: 16:19:2

End Time:   16:19:7


The elapsed time is  3 Hours - 3 Minutes
```

Or:

```
Start Time: 16:19:14

End Time:   16:19:19


The elapsed time is  1 Hours - 1 Minutes
```

But the output should be:

```
The elapsed time is  0 Hours - 0 Minutes
```

I really don't know what's wrong with my `timeCheck` function.
Any way if i fix it some how i need to expand it to print:

```
The elapsed time is  0 Hours - 0 Minutes - 5 Seconds.
```

Comment: In addition to what the answer says, you don't want to call `difftime`. Just subtract `end-start`. `difftime` works with `time_t`, which may or may not be a number of seconds expressed as an integer (that's why difftime is needed in the first place). If you have seconds as two integers, just subtract them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
start = (time_t)((myClock[0].hour * 60 + myClock[1].hour) * 60) ;
end   = (time_t)((myClock[0].minutes * 60 + myClock[1].minutes) * 60) ;
```

This code seems nonsense. I think this should be

```
start = (time_t)((myClock[0].hour * 60 + myClock[0].minutes) * 60 + myClock[0].seconds) ;
end   = (time_t)((myClock[1].hour * 60 + myClock[1].minutes) * 60 + myClock[1].seconds) ;
```

Then, have the function print what you want.

1. add a variable `int second;` after `int minute;`
2. add calculation `second = (int) diff % 60;` after `minute = (int) diff % 3600 / 60;`
3. have it print the result
   `printf("The elapsed time is  %d Hours - %d Minutes - %d Seconds.\n", hour, minute, second);`

Comment: Thank you for your help. My kid will love this. Any way For the part where you said that is nonsense, there was another thing where this function was used and works fine. [Please take a look](http://ideone.com/B2cEhZ). Any way Thank you again.